# cocos2d-html5 menuItem callback

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, callback, cocos2d-html5

i'm new on Cocos2d-html5. i'm making some samples and i can't run a menu item callback.

Menu item sprite is drawed on canvas but doesn't working

can someone help me.

```
var primeraEscena = cc.Scene.extend({
onEnter:function(){
    this._super();
    var layer = new Escenas();
    layer.init();
    this.addChild(layer);
}
})

var Escenas = cc.Layer.extend({
init:function()
{
    this._super();
    try{
    var layer1 = cc.LayerColor.create(new cc.Color4B(255, 255, 255, 255), 600, 600);
    layer1.setAnchorPoint(new cc.Point(0.5,0.5));

    var botonImg = cc.Sprite.create("img/greencircle.png", cc.rect(0, 0, 40, 40));
    var botonImg2 = cc.Sprite.create("img/greencircle.png", cc.rect(1, 0, 40, 40));
    var botonImg3 = cc.Sprite.create("img/greencircle.png", cc.rect(2, 0, 40, 40));
    var boton = cc.MenuItemSprite.create(botonImg, botonImg2,botonImg3, this.func, this);
    try{
        boton.setEnabled(true)
    }catch(e){
        alert(e)
    }
    var menu = cc.Menu.create(boton, null);
    menu.setEnabled(true)
    menu.alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding(10);
    this.addChild(menu);
    }catch(e){alert(e)}

    return true;
}, 
func:function(){
    alert("Wiiii")
}

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed calling setTouchEnabled for the layer

```
this.setTouchEnabled(true);
```

For more details, you can find samples here: http://cocos2d-x.org/npm/ccmenu/index.html